# C# Webservice only returns Interface

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, interface, wsdl

I am currently trying to use a Webservice set up by a big company.
I got the wsdl file manually, which means i couldn't use the tool vs provides to surf to the supplied address(because it required a password, it worked in browser but didn't in vs). So i downloaded it via Webbrowser and then loaded it via "add Service Reference" navigating to the location on my machine. If i want to instanciate the Service via

`Trimet_SAP.z_webservice_fakt MyServ = new Trimet_SAP.z_webservice_fakt();`

i get the error "an Instance of the interface or abstract class couldn't be created" which is clear to me because it is an interface. But that would mean that the WSDL only got me the classes and structures for the data, not the Web IO functionality and i would have to implement building xml, and transmitting as well as handling the raw data of the respone, am i right?

So my question is: Do i have to implement the data transfer myself or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: is this a `WCF` web service..? perhaps you can consult the company that wrote it for documentation usage

Comment: Is that the class you're supposed to be creating? You could search the code to see if there's anything that implements it or inherits from it.